# How to insert pairs into a map based on user input and then find the element associated with a key given by user?

Tags: c++, stl

The following code is not working if I add the part to find the element. Without that part, the 1st part of code is working to add and display elements of a `stl::map`

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<map>
    #include<utility>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        int n, k, q;
        char *v;
        map<int, char*> m1;
        map<int, char*>::iterator it;
        cout << "enter number of elements\n";
        cin >> n;
        cout << "enter number and string- \n";
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            cin >> k;
            cin >> v;
            m1.insert(pair<int, char*>(k, v));
        }
        cout << "elements are- " << endl;
        for (it=m1.begin(); it!=m1.end(); it++)
            cout << it->first << " " << it->second << "\n";

    /* if the code is kept up to this and compiled,
       the map elements are displayed. If the following code is added
       to find the element, the application crashes just after taking
       an input to fill the map */

        cout << "enter a key to find element\n";
        cin >> q;
        it = m1.find(q);
        if(it!=m1.end())
        cout << it->first << " " << it->second ;
        else
            cout << "key was not found\n";

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `char *v` declares a pointer, but it hasn't been made to point to anything. Rather use `std::string`.

Comment: Change `char*` to `string`.  Change `m1.insert(pair<int, char*>(k, v));` to `m1[k] = v;`.  Win!

Comment: @wally Thanks for your response. But this worked to insert the element, it crashes if I add the code to find the element.

Comment: @Eljay Thanks a lot, it worked!!! But could you please explain the reason of the crash. I don't understand why it worked if I just would insert the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `char*` to `string`.  The `char*` is a dangling pointer.  It does not refer to an allocated buffer.  Changing to a `string` will dynamically handle all the details.

Change `m1.insert(pair<int, char*>(k, v));` to `m1[k] = v;`.  The latter way of modifying and accessing a map is one of the reasons to use a map:  for the syntactical convenience.  Nothing "wrong" with the first way, but it's more typing and less clear.